# Unprocessable entity error when sending a form data in fastapi

Tags: python, serialization, path, multipartform-data, fastapi

When I send a multi-part form data it returns the error: "Unprocessable Entity"

the api endpoint:

```
@router.post('/', response_model=schemas.Category)
def add_category(
                 file: UploadFile,
                 category: schemas.CategoryCreate = Depends(schemas.CategoryCreate.as_form), 
                 db: Session = Depends(get_db)
                ):
print(category)
print(file.filename)
```

The BaseModel classes:

```
class ProductCreate(BaseModel):
title: str 
description: str 
price: float 
time: float 
photo_url: str 

@as_form
class CategoryCreate(BaseModel):
name: str
products: List[ProductCreate] = []
```

the as_form function:

```
def as_form(cls: Type[BaseModel]):
new_parameters = []

for field_name, model_field in cls.__fields__.items():
    model_field: ModelField  # type: ignore

    new_parameters.append(
         inspect.Parameter(
             model_field.alias,
             inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY,
             default=Form(...) if not model_field.required else Form(model_field.default),
             annotation=model_field.outer_type_,
         )
     )

async def as_form_func(**data):
    return cls(**data)

sig = inspect.signature(as_form_func)
sig = sig.replace(parameters=new_parameters)
as_form_func.__signature__ = sig  # type: ignore
setattr(cls, 'as_form', as_form_func)
return cls
```

**note :**
When I remove the field:
`products: List[ProductCreate] = []`
from CategoryCreate BaseModel, it works fine!

Thank you in advance

Comment: It expects a list of products and you're probably not sending one; since you haven't defined the field as optional, you're not going to get it validated. However, sending embedded objects in a list isn't straight forward when using regular http POSTed form-data, since there is no recursive structure to those sets of data.

Comment: Does anyone have an updated version of this one for pydantic v2? the `model_field.outer_type_` does not exist anymore